# add nested attributes to python

Tags: python, object, attributes

the following code

```
def _say(x): return x

class newObject(object):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        for x in kw:
            self.x = kw[x]
            for i in self.x:
                a = self.x[i]
                eval('self.x.{u}={t}'.format(u=i, t=a)) #on another note, why would setattr(self.x, i, a) not work
        self.object_ret()

    def object_ret(self):
        return self

data = newObject(**{
        'ranks':{
            'one':['yhggti','aragos','raithinki'],
            'two':['grythin','radios'],
            'three':['riyoken','schrodinger']},
        'nicknames':{
            'riyoken':['theos','arahiron'],
            'illogic':['harab','thing']},
        'commands':{
            'say':_say},
        })
```

outlines how i want to add further attributes to an object on the end of another attribute. I used to have it like

```
class newObject(object):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        [setattr(self, x, kw[x]) for x in kw]
        self.object_ret()
```

where data.nicknames would return 
`>>> data.nicknames
{'illogic': ['harab', 'thing'], 'riyoken': ['theos', 'arahiron']}`
now I wanted to be able to call data.nicknames.riyoken and return `['theos', 'arahiron']` which would not work with the original setup hence the top portion of the code. The `eval('self.x.{u}={t}'.format(u=i, t=a))` part however errors and gives something such as 
`File "<string>", line 1
    self.x.say=<function _say at 0x030E9420>
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
if there is any way possible to get this to work where I could call data.nicknames.riyoken or data.commands.say it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `setattr(self.x, i, a)` should work fine. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: 17, in __init__
    setattr(self.x, i, a)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'two'

Comment: I see now. Indeed, you can't set attributes on a dict (and many other built in types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up a couple of things. Here is a working version that is close to your code:

```
class Attributes:
    pass

class NewObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        for x in kw:
            attrs = Attributes()
            setattr(self, x, attrs)
            for i in kw[x]:
                a = kw[x][i]
                setattr(attrs, i, a)
```

And here is how I would do it:

```
class NewObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                value = NewObject(**value)
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

This will handle arbitrarily nested dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass data as a parameter to the class when you initialize it? So have the class take a dictionary as an argument. Not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I know... I don't have enough reputation >:(

Comment: Well delete this because it's worse now.

Comment: Well at least you are kind and friendly and encouraging contribution

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be mean. I had downvoted because it should have been a comment and I couldn't retract it so I was suggesting you to delete this so that you could get your 2 reputation back. Now that someone has upvoted that no longer applies.